# Separate YAML and plain text on the same document

Tags: yaml, blogs, plaintext, pyyaml

While building a blog using django I realized that it would be extremely practical to store the text of an article and all the related informations (title, author, etc...) together in a human-readable file format, and then charge those files on the database using a simple script.

Now that said, YAML caught my attention for his readability and ease of use, the only downside of the YAML syntax is the indentation:

```
---
title: Title of the article
author: Somebody
# Other stuffs here ...
text:| 
    This is the text of the article. I can write whatever I want
    but I need to be careful with the indentation...and this is a
    bit boring.
---
```

I believe that's not the best solution (especially if the files are going to be written by casual users). A format like this one could be much better

```
---
title: Title of the article
author: Somebody
# Other stuffs here ...
---
Here there is the text of the article, it is not valid YAML but
just plain text. Here I could put **Markdown** or <html>...or whatever
I want...
```

Is there any solution? Preferably using python.
Other file formats propositions are welcome as well!

Comment: Your second code example is exactly valid YAML. It is a YAML stream with two documents where the second one is a plain text scalar. If your YAML parser doesn't support this, then you could consider using a different one. For example, in Ruby: `YAML.load_stream("---\nhello: world\n---\nPlain text")` returns `[{"hello"=>"world"}, "Plain text"]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, what one would think could work is using `|` for a single scalar in the separate document:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
title: Title of the article
author: Somebody
---
|
Here there is the text of the article, it is not valid YAML but
just plain text. Here I could put **Markdown** or <html>...or whatever
I want...
"""

for d in ruamel.yaml.load_all(yaml_str):
    print(d)
    print('-----')
```

but it doesn't because `|` is the [block indentation indicator](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793979). And although at the top level an indentation of 0 (zero) would easily work, ruamel.yaml (and PyYAML) don't allow this.

It is however easy to parse this yourself, which has the advantage over using the front matter package that you can use YAML 1.2 and are not restricted to using YAML 1.1 because of frontmaker using the PyYAML. Also note that I used the more appropriate  end of document marker `...` to separate YAML from the markdown:

```
import ruamel.yaml

combined_str = """\
title: Title of the article
author: Somebody
...
Here there is the text of the article, it is not valid YAML but
just plain text. Here I could put **Markdown** or <html>...or whatever
I want...
"""

with open('test.yaml', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(combined_str)


data = None
lines = []
yaml_str = ""
with open('test.yaml') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if data is not None:
            lines.append(line)
            continue
        if line == '...\n':
            data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
            continue
        yaml_str += line

print(data['author'])
print(lines[2])
```

which gives:

```
Somebody
I want...
```

(the `round_trip_load` allows dumping with preservation of comments, anchor names etc).

Answer (score 0):

I found [Front Matter](http://assemble.io/docs/YAML-front-matter.html) does exactly what I want to do.
There is also [a python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-frontmatter/0.2.1).